# Oracle Substr SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I got list of database.

```
**NAME**
OEE_LINE_ABC
OEE_LINE_ABCD
OEE_LINE_QWERTYUIOP
OEE_LINE_zxcvbd
```

I need to grab the `Name` that after `OEE_LINE_`. But it does not standardize how many characters. What I get from google is fix how many characters.

Example :

```
SUBSTR(Name,10,3)
Result: 'ABC'
```

If I use above substr, it able to grab the 1st value (`OEE_LINE_ABC`) without problem, when comes to 2nd value, there's a problem because above substr only can retrieve 3 characters.

Expected result:

the SQL statement able to grab values that after `OEE_LINE_`

Result(return name without the `OEE_LINE_`):

```
Name = ABC
Name = ABCD
Name = QWERTYUIOP
Name = zxcvbd
```

Any related post to share and answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking for the last `'_`' and taking the string from there:

```
select substr(name, length(name) - instr(reverse(name), '_') + 2)
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, this is working but there is one problem, it's return with an extra `_`. Example - It should return only ABC instead of `_ABC`

Comment: I got the answer already Gordon, I change `+1` to `+2`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
SUBSTR(Name,10,length(Name)-9)
```

Comment: Hi, what does -9 means?

Comment: Hi, you should insert length of your string minus 9 which is length of "OEE_LINE_" instead of 3 in the third parameter of SUBSTR function

Comment: I thought 3 is how many values that I want to grab and 10 is where I wanted to start grab the `Name` , accroding to [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the rest of the string, just specify the start position:

SELECT SUBSTR(name, 10)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5889a/2/0)